# Why the extension of distribution T in $(D(\Omega))^{'}$ to dual of sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ not unique?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

I am trying to understand section about dual of sobolev spaces  from Adam's book "Sobolev Spaces". As I understand it he states that every element in the dual of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open,  can be represented by a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,....,v_N)$ where each $v_i$ is in $L^{q}$ and q is the conjugate exponent of p.N is the number of multi derivate indices that depend on k and n. This also represents an element in the space of distributions $(D(\Omega))^{'}$. But however he says that this representation need not be unique. Can you give an example where there are more than one such representation for elements in the dual $(W^{k,p}(\Omega))^{'}$?

Edited:

Is it possible that there are two different elements in $(W^{k,p}(\Omega))^{'}$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that they agree on $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$. ie is it possible that $T_1{\phi}=T_2{\phi}$ for all $\phi$ in $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ but $T_1{u} \neq T_2{u}$ for some $u$ in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

The relevant section can be found in chapter 3 of the book Adams, R.A. and Fournier, J.J.F, Sobolev Spaces, 2nd ed., Academic Press, 2003.

Comment: I think the point is that this decomposition treats each derivative as an independent variable, but of course by FTC the derivatives are not independent variables, so there could be two such vectors of functions that represent the same function. I don't think it means that a distribution can be non-uniquely extended.

Comment: Indeed the extension being non-unique is exactly the reverse concept: that you are given such a "representation" and it instead represents multiple distinct functions. But that's ridiculous, because the only thing that the extension of an element of $D'$ could be is $\phi(f)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(f_n)$ with the convergence taken in $W^{k,p}$ sense. This must necessarily be unique provided $\phi$ was bounded in the $W^{k,p}$ norm in the first place.

Comment: @user1952009 mlk's answer seems to just be a more precise version of what I said. I guess yours is just a concrete example, which seems a bit odd to me given that the mapping in question was not explicitly specified.

Comment: The statement I am trying to understand is in section 3.11 of the book. Here he says that the distribution T can possesses non unique extensions to $W^{k,p}$. Of course the distribution is uniquely extended via limits to $W_0^{k,p}$ because $C_0^{\infty}$ is dense in $W_0^{k,p}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-uniqueness refers to the vector $v$. Note that for $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in C_0^1(\Omega)$ we have
$$\int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \phi d x = - \int_\Omega f \mathop{div} \phi d x.$$
In other words, if you find a function $\phi \in C_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\mathop{div} \phi = 0$, (and there are many of those) you can add it to the respective components of $v$ without changing the operator. The same of course also can be done in the higher derivatives.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand that more than one $v$ can represent the same element in $(W^{k,p}(\Omega))^{'}$. But is it possible that there are two different elements in $(W^{k,p}(\Omega))^{'}$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that they agree on $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$. ie is it possible that $T_1{\phi}=T_2{\phi}$ for all $\phi$ in $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ but $T_1{u} \neq T_2{u}$ for some $u$ in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @praveenkr There are linear functionals on $W^{k,p}$ that see the boundary values of their input, e.g. $f \mapsto \int_{\partial \Omega} f dS$. These of course all map $C^\infty_0$ to $0$. These are essentially the only examples.

Answer (score -1):

Copying mlk's answer, let $\phi(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x| < 1} \in C^\infty_c[-1,1]$ then 
$$\int_{-1}^1 f'(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\phi'(x)dx$$

---

Also
$$\int_0^a f'(x)x dx = a f(a)-\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
So that $a f(a) =\int_0^a f'(x)x dx+\int_0^1 f(x)dx$
and
$$\int_0^2 f'(x)x dx = 2 f(2)-\int_0^2 f(x)dx=2 f(1)+ 2\int_1^2 f'(x)dx-\int_0^2 f(x)dx\\= 2\int_0^1 f'(x)x dx+2\int_0^1 f(x)dx+2\int_1^2 f'(x)dx-\int_0^2 f(x)dx$$